# JUnit5 test in case of HttpClientErrorException.Unauthorized

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit5

I try to test getLimit() method that returns rate_limit from https://api.github.com.
In this method is try and catch block that catch HttpClientErrorException.Unauthorized exception. Could anyone advise what I'm doing wrong in my test case that result of test is failed with:

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception type thrown,
Expected :class org.example.exception.git.GitUnauthorizedException
Actual   :class org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException

Method:

```
public RateLimitDto getLimit() {
    String apiUrl = GIT_API_URL + "/rate_limit";
    try {
        return restTemplate.getForObject(apiUrl, RateLimitDto.class);
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException.Unauthorized unauthorized) {
        throw new GitUnauthorizedException("User unauthorized!");
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
void getLimitTest_UNAUTHORIZED_ERROR() {
    String apiUrl = GIT_API_URL + "/rate_limit";

    when(restTemplate.getForObject(apiUrl, RateLimitDto.class))
            .thenThrow(new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));

    assertThrows(GitUnauthorizedException.class, () -> {
            gitService.getLimit();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change my test case in this way:

```
@Test
void getLimitTest_UNAUTHORIZED_ERROR() {
    String apiUrl = GIT_API_URL + "/rate_limit";

    HttpClientErrorException.Unauthorized unauthorizedMock = Mockito.mock(HttpClientErrorException.Unauthorized.class);

    doThrow(unauthorizedMock)
            .when(restTemplate).getForObject(apiUrl, RateLimitDto.class);

    assertThrows(GitUnauthorizedException.class, gitService::getLimit);
}
```

When I mocked the authentication exception and provide it to doThrow(mockException), test started to work correct and also covered getLimit() method.